# Obtener el i-ésimo dígito de cada número dentro de un texto con RegEx

Tags: javascript, regex

Mi problema es el siguiente, tengo un texto como el siguiente, `"20784 18892 47924 56215"`. Como se puede ver, el texto tiene números y espacios. Cada número tiene la misma cantidad de dígitos, en este caso 5.

Me gustaría poder extraer sólo el i-ésimo dígito mediante expresiones regulares. Es decir, si la posición es 0, devuelve un array, `["2", "1", "4", "5"]`, si es 1, `["0", "8", "7", "6"]`, si es 5 debería devolver un array de espacios (pero no tendría sentido, así que eso no es necesario), sólo me interesa la parte de los dígitos.

El código que se me ocurre, aunque es obvio que no va a funcionar, es algo como `cadena.match(/\d{5}<posición> /g)`, o algo como `cadena.match(/\d{2}<\d>\d{2} /g)`. Aquí se mostraría el dígito del medio en cada uno.

El código que hice funciona, pero no usa expresiones regulares. ¿Es posible usando expresiones regulares?

```js
function iésima_posición(cadena,posición)
{
 var array=[]
 cadena=cadena.split(" ")
 for(var i=0;i<cadena.length;i++)
 {
  array[array.length]=cadena[i][posición]
 }
 return array
}
var cadena="20784 18892 47924 56215"
for(var i=0;i<5;i++)
{
  var s=iésima_posición(cadena,i)
  console.log(s+"")
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cuando uno quiere **capturar** una parte específica de una coincidencia, tiene que usar un **[grupo](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#Using_Parenthesized_Substring_Matches)**. Un grupo es todo aquello que está **entre paréntesis** en la expresión regular, y tiene el beneficio de que el texto con el que coincidió el subpatrón es guardado en memoria, y luego se puede referenciar o recuperar.

Así, podemos hacer que coincida con N dígitos previos, y luego capturar con un grupo el dígito que nos interese. Para capturar el 3er dígito:

```
/\b\d{2}(\d)/g
```

Significado:

- `\b` - Límite de palabra completa (coincide en la posición antes o después de una palabra). En este caso lo usamos para que coincida en la posición entre el espacio y el inicio de un número (o entre el inicio del texto y el primer número).
- `\d{2}` - Que coincida (y consuma) 2 dígitos.
- `(\d)` - Que coincida (y capture en el primer grupo) 1 dígito.
- `/g` : modificador GLOBAL para que busque todas las coincidencias (no sólo la primera).

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/gkHO9y/1/

---

#### Código:

```js
const regex = /\b\d{2}(\d)/g;
const texto = "20784 18892 47924 56215";
let grupos;

while ((grupos = regex.exec(texto)) !== null) {
    console.log("Tercer dígito:", grupos[1]);
}
```

#### Y de forma dinámica:

```js
function obtenerDigitoN(texto, digito) {
    const regex = new RegExp("\\b\\d{" + (digito - 1) + "}(\\d)", "g");
    let grupos,
        resultado = [];

    while ((grupos = regex.exec(texto)) !== null) {
        //Agregar la captura del 1er grupo al array de resultados
        resultado.push(grupos[1]);
    }
    
    return resultado;
}


// Prueba
const texto = "20784 18892 47924 56215",
      digitoN = 3;

let respuesta = obtenerDigitoN(texto, digitoN);

console.log(respuesta);
```

Comment: genial respuesta y muy instructiva